# Amazon Elasticsearch 1.5 hangs while re-indexing

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

I m using a micro ES instance from Amazon with 2 nodes.

However, while I m re-indexing my data (around 300.000 docs, 300MB), the instance becomes unresponsive several times. It usually hangs when trying to read from the instance at the same time.

I m using this instance for the production of my website, and this issue causes me big headaches.

Anyone experiencing same issues? Would it help If I move to:
1) larger instance?
2) upgrade to 2.X version?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only time I've had issues with ES queries being unresponsive during re-indexing is when the resources are exhausted, so I would advocate a larger instance.

You should use CloudWatch metrics to determine the resource usage on your current instance during a period where it's running well and also during your re-index. Use this information to decide the best instance type accordingly, the following table will give you an idea of what resource you get https://aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/pricing/

Comment: So the instance is 1GB memory and also using 10Gb EBS. Each time there are around 300.000 docs (300MB). When I reindex my data I m using a seperate index, so in that time once it finishes there are ~600K docs and ~600MB. Why the 1Gb is not enough??

Comment: Running the service even without an index will consume some resource, also Elastic recommend having memory spare for the OS and Lucene to avoid swapping to disk, which I believe is what is happening in your case when you index. I'm not sure that AWS optimisations will have removed all of those overheads, and you are still basically running on the smallest EC2 instance with 1GB for OS + Elasticsearch.

Comment: Ok I see, thnx NHol